# Error adding foreign key in migration [Laravel 8] (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have my `users`

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->enum('role', ['admin', 'operator', 'owner']);
            $table->string('password');
            $table->foreignId('profile_id')->constrained('profile');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I have my `profile`

```
Schema::create('profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('full_name');
            $table->bigInteger('phone');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->enum('gender', ['men', 'women']);
        });
```

Everytime I tried to migrate it popped up error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `myDatabase`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_profile_id_foreign` foreign key (`profile_id`) references `profile` (`id`))
```

I heard and know this error can happen if the both data type is not the same, since I have encounter this problem before and manage to fix it by making sure both data type is the same. But I think the data type is already the same right? Am I missing something? Or the problem is not the data type? Thanks!

Comment: Which table are you creating first? Are you trying to reference `profile.id` before it is available?

Comment: Ohh right. My `users` table is created first, and yeah because of that I reference `profile.id` before it's available. Thanks! I fixed it by changing my migration order

Comment: Perfect! So yes, you can either change the order, or link the two in the `profile` table migration (`Schema::table('users') ... // logic to link users.profile_id to profiles.id)`), whichever works for you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The known cause of this problem would the sequence, If your "**Users**" migration file is running before "**Profile**" Migration file, then this scenario can happen.

The solution would be is to change the migration filename so that "Profile" migration file runs first.